# Timespan INotifyPropertyChanged from another class which does not implement it

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

Trying to keep track of a timespan variable inside class I'm using.

to be more specific Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture.ScreenCaptureJob class

but really the question ain't really specific to that class.

so I'm wondering if there is any alternative way for me to keep track of the timespan...

Extra Notes:

- None of the inherited class from the above class contain the INotifyPropertyChanged
- Displaying on WPF form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be event based.

what about wrapping the class with INotifyPropertyChanged, periodically check the property and fire event within the wrapper, then bind via reactive extensions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896

Comment: There is some events but not the ones I'm looking for. Especially, since I just want to display the timer it has. I'll look into the reactive extensions and notify you on changes. Thanks for the info.

Comment: yes I realized this and edited the answer, perhaps the wrapper and checking on another thread could help

Comment: but anyway, why do you need to bind to that class, when you can simply start your own timer on Start() and then stop it on Stop()

Comment: this is how to observer a property, but you need INotifyPropertyChanged http://geekswithblogs.net/Silverlight2/archive/2010/11/30/observe-a-property-in-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlightwpf-using-rx.aspx

Comment: for any .net, where you use events